# android RelativeLayout error " No resource identifier found...."

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am trying to program my first relative layout in Android.

I have a linear layout that works fine and so my relative layout xml file is based on it.

I get the following error :

```
    error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_bottom' in package 'android'
```

The xml (partial) code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="--"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    /> 

    <RadioGroup                                <-- the error is given in this line
          android:id="@+id/kk"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_bottom="@id/text_1"
          >
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make changes as follows :

```
   <RadioGroup
          android:id="@+id/kk"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_below="@id/text_1"
       />
```

Comment: Do consider accepting people's answer by clicking the tick button if it works. Especially in this case. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

It's not `layout_bottom`, it's `layout_alignBottom`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

Comment: Thanks @dmon, I read the link and I achieved the desired behaviour with android:layout_below